# Spring boot configure MessageInterpolator @Bean

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

I am using Spring boot v1.4 and hibernate v4.3.5.finall in my application

I have writen my own ResourceBundle and MessageInterpolator to save messages in database and have configured them as bean in my project. It seems ResourceBundle works fine and returns my custom message but parameters don't pass,for example for this validation :

```
@Size(min=5,max = 10)
private String lastName;
```

I expect : size must be between 5 and 10 bla bla.....

but the result is : size must be between {min} and {max} bla bla.....

any Idea? Thanks..

my ResourceBundle  class:

```
package ir.pt.core.bundles;

import ir.pt.common.bean.ResourceEntity;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class DatabaseResourceBundle extends ResourceBundle {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;
    private Map<String, String> cache = new HashMap<String, String>();
    protected final static String BUNDLE_NAME = "ir.pt.core.bundles";
    protected Control DB_CONTROL = new DBControl();

    public DatabaseResourceBundle() {

        setParent(ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME, DB_CONTROL));
    }

    public DatabaseResourceBundle(Locale locale) {
        setParent(ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME, locale, DB_CONTROL));
    }

    @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
        return cache != null ? cache.get(key) : parent.getObject(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
        return parent.getKeys();
    }

    protected class DBControl extends Control {

        @Override
        public ResourceBundle newBundle(String baseName, Locale locale, String format, ClassLoader loader, boolean reload)
                throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, IOException {
            return new CustomizedLocaleResources(locale);
        }

        protected class CustomizedLocaleResources extends ListResourceBundle {
            private Locale locale;
            public CustomizedLocaleResources(Locale locale) {
                this.locale = locale;
            }

            @Override
            protected Object[][] getContents() {
                String sql = "FROM ResourceEntity re WHERE re.locale = '"+locale.getLanguage()+"'";
                TypedQuery<ResourceEntity> query =
                em.createQuery(sql, ResourceEntity.class);
                List<ResourceEntity> resources = query.getResultList();
                Object[][] all = new Object[resources.size()][2];
                int i = 0;
                for (Iterator<ResourceEntity> it = resources.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    ResourceEntity resource = it.next();
                    all[i] = new Object[]{resource.getKey(), resource.getMessage()};
                    cache.put(resource.getKey(), resource.getMessage());
                    i++;
                }
                return all;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

my MessageInterpolator class:

```
package ir.pt.core.bundles;

import org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import javax.validation.MessageInterpolator;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;


public class DatabaseMessageInterpolator extends ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator implements MessageInterpolator{
    protected final String BRACE_OPEN = "\\{";
    protected final String BRACE_CLOSE = "\\}";

    @Autowired
    DatabaseResourceBundle databaseResourceBundle;

    @Override
    public String interpolate(String message, Context context) {

        return interpolate(message, context, databaseResourceBundle.getLocale());
    }

    @Override
    public String interpolate(String message, Context context, Locale locale) {
        String messageKey = context.getConstraintDescriptor().getAttributes().get("message").toString();
        message = databaseResourceBundle.getString(messageKey.replaceAll(BRACE_OPEN, "").replaceAll(BRACE_CLOSE, ""));
        Map<String, Object> attributes = context.getConstraintDescriptor().getAttributes();
        for (String key : attributes.keySet()) {
            String value = attributes.get(key).toString();
            key = BRACE_OPEN + key + BRACE_CLOSE;
            message = message.replaceAll(key, value);
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

my bean configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean factory = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        factory.setMessageInterpolator(messageInterpolator());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageInterpolator messageInterpolator() {
        return new DatabaseMessageInterpolator();
    }

    @Bean
    ResourceBundle resourceBundle() {
        return new DatabaseResourceBundle(new Locale("fa"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I had problems of this kind, and in all cases the only way I found to resolve them was first to debug the situation when I did not use custom components (in your case the custom message interpolator), then debug with the custom component used, and then it usually becomes clear why the parameters inside the message are not set (or why there are any other problems with the messages); and how the custom component should be changed to achieve the correct result. Certainly not by looking at the documentation :)

Comment: thanks for reply @John Donn, but the thing is its such an another concept, its a Bean and gets configured in Spring Framework skeleton, I can not set it and its my problem probably.